# Difference/similarities: Field of rational functions in X - smallest field containing K and x?

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

I am a bit confused with the Notation $K(X)$ or $K(x)$. In my notes I found two definitions:

- $K(X)$ is the field of rational functions with indeterminate $X$.
- $K(x)$ is the smallest field containing $K$ and $x$. For example $\mathbb{R}(i) = \mathbb{C}$

Now I don't quite see how I should be able to distinguish these two uses of $K(x)$ or I don't see that these two concepts are the same.

If the two are the same, wouldn't that mean that $K(X)$ is an extension of $K$? But how can an element of $K$ be an element of $K(X)$, which contains functions?

I tried to search about this, but haven't found any sources which deal with both these fields at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's somewhat of an abuse of notation, but an acceptable one, because there is a trivial embedding of $K$ into $K(X)$, in the same way that $K$ embeds into the polynomial ring $K[X]$ with indeterminate $X$. In both cases the embedding is just the map from an element in $K$ to the corresponding constant function.

More precisely, let $φ(a) = ( X \mapsto a )$ for any $a \in K$. Then $φ$ is clearly a ring or field homomorphism from $K$ to $K[X]$ or $K(X)$ respectively.

Also, it is true that even if you interpret $K(X)$ as a field whose elements are (true) functions, it is still indeed isomorphic to $K(x)$ for any $x$ in a field extension of $K$ such that $x$ is not algebraic over $K$. In other words, extending a field by adjoining an indeterminate is essentially the same as adjoining a transcendental element (in a larger containing field). That is probably why you don't see many sources talk about both at the same time, as they are no different in structure.

Finally, I should mention that you must not forget what exactly you mean when you talk about common concepts like $i = \sqrt{-1}$. Technically speaking there is no such thing until you have shown that there is really a field containing $\mathbb{R}$ that has an element $i$ such that $i^2 = -1$. If you have not, then you can't just talk about $\mathbb{R}(i)$ since you **must already have** such a larger field to begin with, before you can talk about the smallest field containing $\mathbb{R}$ as well as $i$.

Comment: I just need some confirmation: examples for the isomorphism between $\mathbb{Q}(\pi)$ (as the rational field and the transcendental $\pi$) and $\mathbb{Q}(X)$ (as the (rational-valued?) rational functions) would be $\frac{\pi^3+1}{\pi+1} \mapsto (X \mapsto \frac{X^3+1}{X+1})$

Comment: @Cyril: Precisely. $\mathbb{Q}(π)$ makes sense because both $\mathbb{Q}$ and $π$ lie in the larger field $\mathbb{R}$. This field is indeed isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}(X)$ by the isomorphism generated by $π \mapsto X$ as you have shown in your example. Indeed you can check that it is an isomorphism, though it's easier to prove the reverse map $X \mapsto π$ is an isomorphism. Before that, note that both of these maps are not well-defined until you prove that you can select a representative. For the reverse map, we choose rational expressions with numerator and denominator having gcd one. [...]

Comment: @Cyril: It is clearly a homomorphism and almost as clearly surjective. You need a little bit of work to show that it is injective, basically since otherwise there is a nonzero rational function that gets mapped to $0$, which gives nonzero polynomials $P,Q$ such that $\frac{P(π)}{Q(π)} = 0$, which is impossible since $P(π) \ne 0$.

Comment: @Cyril: As for your last question, $\mathbb{Q}(X)$ are called "rational functions" but that term has nothing to do with rationals. In general for any field $F$ we still call $F(X)$ the field of rational functions over $F$. You might be asking what the domain of these functions are. Structure wise it does not matter, just like polynomial functions, because only the coefficients matter. Just like we can define polynomial addition and multiplication simply in terms of manipulations of their coefficients, we can do the same for rational functions.

Comment: @Cyril: That is why some people do not consider them as true functions but rather as merely two strings of symbols (or two finite sequences of coefficients), one for the numerator and one for the denominator. Also, you'll face trouble in choosing an appropriate domain, since for instance your example rational function cannot be applied to $-1$ otherwise you get division by zero. It turns out that in this special case $\mathbb{Q}(X)$ can be embedded by the obvious map into the field of meromorphic functions, but I'm not sure about the general case.